# Taking 1 specific item out of JSON response using Python

Tags: python, json, response

I am trying to get "id" number and use it in program afterwards. Response is .json if that matters

```
{"run_at":1818086502,"quantity":295092,"queue":"units","original_duration":388900193,"duration":388900193,"unit_type":"Harrier","city_id":1102142875,"id":3720348749},"success":true}}
```

This is part of response where "id" is.

And this is what i have so far:

```python
cadena= "Draoumculiasis" + params + "LandCrocodile" + url + "Bevar-Asp" 
cadenau=cadena.encode('utf8')
m=hashlib.sha1(cadenau)
xs3=m.hexdigest()
headers= { 'Host': realm , 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': len(params), 'Origin': 'http://castlemania-production.s3.amazonaws.com', 'x-s3-aws': xs3, 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'DNT': 1, 'Cookie': cookie }
conn=http.client.HTTPConnection(realm,80)
conn.request("POST",url,params, headers)
response=conn.getresponse()
```

Id changes every time.

I have made part that makes id and that uses id, i need to connect those two without typing it manually.
Sadly i'm not programmer so i'm looking for complete solution if possible. I've done some research but could not figure it out.

**Update 1**

As suggested in Gord's answer I use

```python
responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
items = json.loads(responseData)
```

and now I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Files\doa\Py's\testinggettingid.py", line 54, in <module>
    items = json.loads(responseData)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Update 2 
I've removed the error by

```
    response=conn.getresponse() 
responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
print(responseData)
items = json.loads(responseData)
idValue = items['id']
print(idValue)
```

But it shows my player id instead of a job id.

Update 3

print(response.getheaders()) as per request

[image]

Comment: *"i'm not programmer so i'm looking for complete solution if possible"* - this isn't a code-writing service; if you need a developer, hire one. Do note, though, that both code and JSON data are text - why on earth have you provided them as off-site screenshots?!

Comment: I see no `id` in the URLs. Please don't link to screenshots. Include images or code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code and/or sample data *as text*. Screenshots are not very helpful (especially when they are posted on ad-laden sites that apparently require Flash).

Comment: My apologies, 1st time posting. Edited and if i knew developer i would hire it ^^ I doubt it is hard for someone with experience but it is for me.

Comment: Your JSON format is invalid

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, i just got told it is http response... Could i get json from that or what do i need to read to get it from http response (if it is possible to get specific part out of it)? thank you

Comment: Tell the person who is responsible for constructing the JSON response that he needs to fix it

Comment: @TimCastelijns, you mean in code i posted? If so then that is not possible. Thank you for your help

Comment: Why not? Anyway it becomes valid if you remove the first and last `}`

Comment: You mean under headers? This code works if i want to print response. What i want it to do is to take "id" part of response. which is making me nuts atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a simplified example where your line of code

```python
>>> response=conn.getresponse()
```

has retrieved the response from the server and saved it as an [HTTPResponse object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html), and when you `.read()` the response you see a JSON string like this

```python
>>> responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> responseData
'{"day": "Thursday", "id": 3720348749}'
```

You can use Python's built-in JSON decoder to convert that into a Dictionary object named `items`

```python
>>> import json
>>> items = json.loads(responseData)
```

Now you can extract the `id` value by referring to the Dictionary entry whose key is 'id'

```python
>>> idValue = items['id']
>>> print(idValue)
3720348749
```

If you run the same code tomorrow and the `response` object that is returned contains

```python
>>> responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> responseData
'{"day": "Friday", "id": 4567890123}'
```

then the same set of steps will extract the new value for `id`

```python
>>> import json
>>> items = json.loads(responseData)
>>> idValue = items['id']
>>> print(idValue)
4567890123
```

**Update**

If your actual JSON data contains nested elements then you may need to use several "key" values to identify the item you want. For example if the "id" you want to retrieve is actually

```python
result
    job
        id
```

i.e., the JSON looks like

```python
'{"result": {"job": {"id": 12345678}}}'
```

then you will need to use

```python
idValue = items['result']['job']['id']
```

Comment: I feel really stupid now.

I get: Typeerror: the json object must be str, not 'HTTPresponse'. 

Does this means it is not json? :/

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6vbsko apologize for link, have no idea how to post code here. 
This is error i am facing now. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Jacob For help on posting code when you edit your question, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). As for the error, it appears that `responseData` contains stuff that the JSON decoder does not understand. Have your script `print(responseData)` and then show us what it looks like. If it is quite large then please post it to a site like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then post the link here. Please include the *entire* `responseData`, not just what you think may be relevant. (If some data is confidential then obfuscate it as XXXXX or similar, but don't just remove it.)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LrXLFxGj This is full response. I can get this through my script too (when i decode it too) but the minute i add instructions for getting "id" i get error from before.

Comment: @Jacob That is valid JSON (except where numbers were obfuscated with XXXXX -- sorry, I probably should have recommended 11111) and my copy of Python 3.4 can decode it. Please `print(response.getheaders())` and update your question to show us what that looks like.

Comment: I found 1 problem. There is another "id". Required one is under "job".

Comment: @Jacob Okay, I have updated my answer re: possible multiple "id" values.

Comment: Eh old problem again when i try to use that same id i just took. 
Works perfectly when it only has to print it but when i try to use it in continuation of a program i get this error: http://prntscr.com/6vbsko

Comment: You have already extracted the required "id" value and saved it to a variable named `idValue`. There is no need to call `json.loads()` again; just use the value in `idValue`. If you need a second value from the JSON data (despite the title of your question) then just extract it from the `items` Dictionary object exactly like you did for the "id" value.

Comment: If it is not too much to ask can we move this to chat?

Comment: I think you need a reputation score of at least 20 before you can [talk in chat](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: @Jacob "unexpected unindent" means that your code indentation (if/for/try block structure) does not make sense to the Python interpreter, which is a separate issue from the topic of this question. If you need help with that then you should ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a JSON response and you want to extract the value of a field named "id". From your question it appears that you are unfamiliar with JSON syntax. Please consult [W3schools' JSON syntax manual](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) and/or [the documentation for Python's JSON library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) if this is the case.

```
import json
response = json.loads("{\"msg\": {\"run_at\":1818086502,\"quantity\":295092,\"queue\":\"units\",\"original_duration\":388900193,\"duration\":388900193,\"unit_type\":\"Harrier\",\"city_id\":1102142875,\"id\":3720348749},\"success\": true}")
print response["msg"]["id"]
```

The above code prints the value of the field "id" in the object "msg".

Comment: Yeah you understood me. But, i don't know how to get id when it different in every response.

Comment: But the structure of the JSON object is surely the same every time, yes?

Comment: Yes it is always the same.

Comment: Can you please post the entire JSON response?

Comment: It is kinda too long. Not sure how to post it whole. Has over 3k characters.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the response piece you posted, although I don't see how it became any clearer. If you are still unable to apply this to your problem, you should take a JSON tutorial, e.g. this one: http://www.w3schools.com/json/.

Comment: It is clearer.But it still doesn't take new id, it uses the one that is written in message. Well guess it's time for tutorial. Thank you.